# How do I add a variable/variables to a list

Tags: list, variables, input, append, extend

I need to find a way how to append a person (form inputs I got) to a list. I always get:<**main**.List object at 0x0000027FD63B6B60>

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, phone_number):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def __str__(self):
        return f"\n{self.name} " + f"\t" + f"{self.surname} " + f"\t" + f"{self.age} " + f"\t" + f"{self.phone_number} "


class Input:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def input_data(self):
        self.name = input("\nInsert a name: \n")
        self.surname = input("Insert a surname: \n")
        self.age = int(input("Insert an age: \n"))
        self.phone_number = input("Insert a phone number: \n") 
        person = NewPerson(self.name, self.surname, self.age, self.phone_number)
        return person

class List:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def data_to_list(self, name, surname, age, phone_number):
        self.name = name
        self.surnam = surnam
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        list= []
        list = list.extend(self.name, self.surname, self.age, self.phone_number)
        return list
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use variable names named after Python's built-ins (`list`), use `lst` for example.

Also, `list.extend` always returns `None` so there's no point to assign the return value to a variable.

In constructor of class `List` assign to `self` an empty list and in method `data_to_list()` use `list.append` to put newly crated `Person()` to a list.

For example:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, phone_number):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person({self.name}, {self.surname}, {self.age}, {self.phone_number})"


class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def data_to_list(self, name, surname, age, phone_number):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.lst.append(
            Person(self.name, self.surname, self.age, self.phone_number)
        )


l = List()
l.data_to_list("John", "Smith", "33", "+123456")
l.data_to_list("Alice", "Green", "32", "+654321")

print(l.lst)
```

Prints:

```
[Person(John, Smith, 33, +123456), Person(Alice, Green, 32, +654321)]
```